Using ieeeconf template and use \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} \bibliography{references}{} for reference,but do not fit in
while using

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} \bibliography{references}{}

for creating references, The references I got looks like
However,the one in the template using bibitem looks like

I cannot find what the style is.

Welcome to TeX.SE. You mention using some kind of template -- does it provide its own \bibliographystyle directive? Please advise.

Unfortunately no.It is the official template of IEEE conference paper,"Preparation of Papers for IEEE Sponsored Conferences & Symposia",which can be viewed in https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/preparation-of-papers-for-ieee-sponsored-conferences-and-symposia/zfnqfzzzxghk.
